# ELMAH logging when customErrors mode= 'Off' and error is cleared in Application_Error event

Tags: asp.net, elmah

This question relates to using ELMAH in an ASP.Net application.
I have the following in my web.config.

```
<customErrors mode="Off" ">
</customErrors>
```

Also, whenever an unhandled error occurs, I clear it in Application_Error event as in code below.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Server.ClearError();
  Response.Redirect("~/errorpages/error.aspx");
}
```

**My question** : Will ELMAH log and email the error in this situation? I have the standard configuration for ELMAH in the web.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if the `Application_Error event is reached, then ELMAH will log and email` the error, even though you clear the error by calling Server.Clear method.
But if, your code does not reach Application_Error event, then ELMAH will NOT log  and email the error.